# Change variable colors vim

Tags: vim, customization

I have installed nord-vim plugin, and when I testing how it see the new plugin I saw the color variables very dark blue.

[image: Vim color]

How can I change that color?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
:set background=dark
```

You can use [`:set background=dark`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27background%27) to switch to an alternate dark color scheme.

> Setting this option does not change the background color, it tells Vim what the background color looks like.

To make the change permanent, put it in your `~/.vimrc`.